# An importerror while importing some package from pytorch3d

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch3d

I tried the following code and got the import error:

```
import os
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from pytorch3d.utils import ico_sphere
import numpy as np
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

from pytorch3d.io import load_objs_as_meshes, save_obj

from pytorch3d.loss import (
    chamfer_distance, 
    mesh_edge_loss, 
    mesh_laplacian_smoothing, 
    mesh_normal_consistency,
)

from pytorch3d.structures import Meshes
from pytorch3d.renderer import (
    look_at_view_transform,
    OpenGLPerspectiveCameras, 
    PointLights, 
    DirectionalLights, 
    Materials, 
    RasterizationSettings, 
    MeshRenderer, 
    MeshRasterizer,  
    SoftPhongShader,
    SoftSilhouetteShader,
    SoftPhongShader,
    TexturesVertex
)
```

Here I am providing the complete traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/parallels/Documents/Program_training/Framework/Framework-HW5/run.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pytorch3d.utils import ico_sphere
  File "/home/parallels/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch3d/utils/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ico_sphere import ico_sphere
  File "/home/parallels/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch3d/utils/ico_sphere.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pytorch3d.ops.subdivide_meshes import SubdivideMeshes
  File "/home/parallels/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch3d/ops/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .graph_conv import GraphConv
  File "/home/parallels/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch3d/ops/graph_conv.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pytorch3d import _C
ImportError: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm running my code on Ubuntu Virtual machine,and my device is a Mac without cuda-support gpu,so I install pytorch and pytorch3d in this way,
For pytorch:

```
pip3 install torch==1.10.0+cpu torchvision==0.11.1+cpu torchaudio==0.10.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch_stable.html
```

For pytorch3d:

```
pip install pytorch3d
```

Please help me to solve this error,any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Plainly the PyTorch3D build you have installed is a CUDA build. I would guess you need a non-CUDA build to make this work